# My MacBook Pro touch bar 13" isn't starting

Tags: macbook-pro, power, power-management, touch-bar

My MacBook Pro touch bar 13" isn't starting and here's what I'm seeing:

1) No power - I can't hear blowers or any sound or see any activity on the backlight when I press the power button/touch ID
2) no keyboard light - neither the caps lock will illuminate nor will the touch bar light up

I mean it's like a laptop without battery nothing happening when I try to open the laptop, I'm sure that the battery wasn't low on charge when I shutdown it yesterday night.

My research shows that a [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) can fix issues when the power button isn't respongind but this reset did not work.

1. Unplug all USB connections - wait 15 seconds
2. Plug back in only the charger that was good yesterday - listen for charge chime - silence
3. Press the TouchID/Power - wait 15 seconds
4. press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. Since I have a MacBook Pro with Touch ID, the Touch ID button is also the power button.
5. Release all keys
6. Press the power button one time

Are there any tricks or other steps before I go to Apple store?

Comment: I've edited this to link to the SMC reset procedure - it's actually quite lengthy and you will want to repeat them with the times specified in seconds to be sure the SMC reset was effective. A second reset won't hurt things.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have the same problem with my MBP. Just brought it to the appleStore in Oberhausen(Germany) it was a hardware trouble which could be fixed within 2 hours.

I didn’t need to pay for that. So if you want to get a quick solution you should go to the appleStore or a reseller.  It could be a bad cable, bad power adapter or something internal needing replacement or reseating a cable.

Hope that this helped you.

Comment: Oh so that means the problem is not that much big and it needs some HW troubleshoot only, thanks.

Comment: And did you ask about the cause what it was happened ? @Fabian

Comment: @GovindKumar TBH yes I did.  But the only thing they told me was that there’s a hardware failure